# Python: saving objects and using pickle. Error using pickle.dump

Tags: python, object, save, pickle

Hello I have an Error and I don´t the reason:

```
>>> class Fruits:pass
...
>>> banana = Fruits()
>>> banana.color = 'yellow'
>>> banana.value = 30
>>> import pickle
>>> filehandler = open("Fruits.obj",'w')
>>> pickle.dump(banana,filehandler)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python31\lib\pickle.py", line 1354, in dump
Pickler(file, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
>>>
```

I don´t know how to solve this error because I don´t understand it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: works for me. Was the namespace somehow polluted before this?

Comment: @Andrew Jaffe:Sorry...I don´t understand you...what do you mean?

Comment: Does it work if these are the very first things that you do in a python session?

Comment: I corrected it based on the answer below and now it works, but I don´t still how to load my objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open your **filehandler** in binary mode, use **wb** instead of **w**:

```
filehandler = open(b"fruits.obj","wb")
```